# Two signer with API in PHP example

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to send one envelope with two or more signers, but I didn´t found how I do it. Using the example with one signer work fine, but how can I add a second signer in this envelope?

following a part of code:
 The signer object

```
$signer1 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer(['email' => $signerEmail1, 'name' => $signerName1, 'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1" ]);
***$signer2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer(['email' => $signerEmail2, 'name' => $signerName2, 'recipient_id' => "2", 'routing_order' => "2" ]);***

# DocuSign SignHere field/tab object
$signHere1 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere(['document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '1',  'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '195', 'y_position' => '147' ]);
```

I tried this:

```
***$signHere2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere(['document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '1',  'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '195', 'y_position' => '147' ]);***

# Add the tabs to the signer object
# The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
$signer1->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere1]]));
```

I tryed this:

```
$signer2->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere2]])); 


# Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
$envelopeDefinition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition(['email_subject' => "Por favor assinar este documento",'documents' => [$document],  'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer1]]) ,'status' => "sent"] );


#
#  Step 2. Create/send the envelope.
#
$config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
$config->setHost($basePath);
$config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " . $accessToken);
$apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
$envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
$results = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelopeDefinition);
return $results;
```

};

I´m using the latest example:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And, very important, please CHECK the best answer to your own questions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs belong to signers. Here is a solution:

```
# Untested code for two signers, each with one signHere tab

# The signer object
$signer = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([ 
    'email' => $signerEmail, 'name' => $signerName, 
    'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1"
]);

# Signer object #2
$signer2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([ 
    'email' => $signerEmail2, 'name' => $signerName2, 
    'recipient_id' => "2", 'routing_order' => "2"
]);

# DocuSign SignHere field/tab object
$signHere = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ 
    'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '1', 
    'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '195', 'y_position' => '147'
]);

# DocuSign SignHere field/tab object #2
$signHere2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ 
    'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '2', 
    'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '395', 'y_position' => '147'
]);

# Add the tabs to the signer objects
# The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
$signer->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(
    ['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere]])); 
$signer2->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(
    ['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere2]])); 

# Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
$envelopeDefinition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
    'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
    'documents' => [$document], # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
    # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
    'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(
        ['signers' => [$signer, $signer2]]), 
    'status' => "sent" # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
]);
```

Comment: I did it now. Sorry I'm new here.